# why can't this c# program be piped to like the "more" command? (And what C functionality does/might 'more' or 'uniq' use to handle piped data?)

Tags: c#, console

If I look at a command that takes stdin, be it the `more` command in windows, or the `uniq` command in linux, you can enter the command, hit ENTER, then enter a line and it echos it back

But you can also echo some text pipe it to the command and the command outputs that and exits. I'm trying to write a C# program that does that.. i'll get to that. But i'll further describe the behaviour i'm trying to produce in my program (And i'd like to know what C functionality those programs use or might use to get that behaviour, and to what extent it exists in C#)

For example

```
C:\abc>more<ENTER>
a<ENTER>
a
b<ENTER>
b
c<ENTER>
c
^C
```

and

```
C:\abc>echo a|more<ENTER>
a


C:\abc>
```

same thing with uniq

```
$ echo a|uniq
a

$ uniq
a
a
b
b
c
c
```

I am trying to get that behaviour in a C sharp program

```
C:\abc>type b.csc
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Console.ReadLine();
   }
}

C:\abc>
```

But of course that program you enter one line and hit ENTER and it's the end of the program

```
C:\abc>b.exe
asdf

C:\abc>
```

So I tried adjusting it

```
C:\abc>type b2.csc
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
         string a;
           while(true) {
          a=Console.ReadLine();
           System.Console.WriteLine(a);
            }
   }
}

C:\abc>
```

And it's ok for the behaviour when just running it and hitting ENTER without pipe

```
C:\Users\harvey>csc b2.csc
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.18408
for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


C:\abc>b2.exe<ENTER>
a<ENTER>
a
b<ENTER>
b
^C
C:\abc>
```

But if I do

```
C:\abc>echo a|b2.exe
```

Then it clears the whole screen

I would like it to do the same as what the `more` command does or the uniq command does when piping to it.

I'm wondering what kind of function those programs use.

What C functionality they use, and whether C# has an equivalent

Ideal answer would include C and C# code that produces that behaviour.

Comment: technically, with piping, most apps don't do anything. they just keep reading input from stdin, and writing output to stdout. the fact  that their stdin/stdout have been remapped to something other than the console is usually not relevant.

Comment: Moreover, programs that can serve as elements of a pipeline exit -- or at least close their `stdout` -- when they reach end-of-file on `stdin`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger maybe not just EOF 'cos ctrl-c too. A good list list of control characters here https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/c0.html  also  this isn't specific about which codes or control characters but https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx "The read operation terminates when the method returns null, which indicates that no lines remain to be read."

Comment: @barlop control characters are not the point.  There's no particular *problem* with them, but they don't much factor in to usage in pipeline context.  Handling EOF is a separate and important issue, as your second code sample demonstrates.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  I never said there was a problem with control characters. My point to you is that to say handling EOF suggests specifically EOF and that perhaps other code would handle other indicators if there are any. Actually readLine()==null is handling indicators of no more lines, which it doesn't define further, but  includes EOF and ETX and perhaps others. To say that, is far more accurate a statement than that it is handling or testing for EOF.

Comment: Could whoever downvoted this question comment on why.

Comment: @barlop Actually (tested in windows cmd), System.Console.ReadLine()==null doesn't detect  Ctrl-C(ETX).   A Ctrl-C exits the program completely.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx   "The ReadLine method executes synchronously. That is, it blocks until a line is read or the Ctrl+Z keyboard combination is pressed"     and "If the Ctrl+Z character is pressed when the method is reading input from the console, the method returns null. This enables the user to prevent further keyboard input when the ReadLine method is called in a loop. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to do it. ReadLine() in a loop with testing for null to break it.

The System.Console.ReadLine() msdn documentation says that it returns "The next line of characters from the input stream, or null if no more lines are available."   That is not very precise..  But msdn documentation gets more precise where it says specifically **Ctrl-Z**. (one might miss that since it writes it as Ctrl+Z).   IF Ctrl-C is hit then the program terminates. So, it's only with Ctrl-Z where ReadLine() returns null.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx

"If the Ctrl+Z character is pressed when the method is reading input from the console, the method returns null. This enables the user to prevent further keyboard input when the ReadLine method is called in a loop. "

All control characters are listed here https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/c0.html

```
public class asdf
{
   public static void Main()
   {
         string a;
           while(true) {
          a=System.Console.ReadLine();
           System.Console.WriteLine(a);
           if(a==null) break;
            }
           System.Console.WriteLine("blah");
   }
}
```

output

```
C:\abc>echo a|b2.exe
a


C:\abc>
```

Comment: i suppose that doesn't explain the clearing the screen part though, why one of the examples in the question cleared the screen